# Do I need to use delete for each new in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

If I have a function like:

```
void MyFunctoin(int size){
// ...
int *arr=new int[size];
// ...
}
```

- Is there a memory leak?
- If yes, is there a way to solve it without using `delete`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your title question is simple: yes, every `new` must be matched by a `delete`. In your case, since you used `new[]`, there must be a `delete[]` somewhere.

But you don't need to write it yourself. It is usually much better to use a class that manages its own resources. In your case, you'd be better off using an STL container such as `array<>` or `vector<>`. This is, either:

```
std::array<int, size> arr; // fixed size (known at compile time)
```

or

```
std::vector<int> arr; // variable size
```

In `vector`, all the necessary calls to `new` and `delete` are done inside the container and you needn't care about them.

You could write your function this way:

```
#include <vector>

void MyFunctoin(int size){
  // ...
  std::vector<int> arr(size);
  // ...
}
```

and there would not be any memory leak with no need to call `delete` anywhere. You don't need to specify `size` when constructing `arr` if you don't want to.

Comment: `std::array` has not any `new/delete` inside, and it's not an alternative to dynamic arrays.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `std::array` uses `new` or `delete` at all internally. I just said that *all the necessary calls* to those functions are performed inside the containers. OP just wants to get rid of calls to `delete`. As to dynamic arrays, that's why I included `std::vector`. OP's code is not valid C++ code anyway, since `size` needs to be constant. It is valid C, though.

Comment: @Gotpik: His code is _valid_ in in C++, `new` doesn't require constant size. In C there is no `new` keyword, so it's not valid there. Addressing `array` as a container which has `new/delete` inside, just mislead newbies because `array` is not a dynamic container.

Comment: OK, you are right with the array size, sorry. I will edit my answer to make it clearer that *fixed size* means fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. Use `smart pointers`/`STL containers` (for example `std::vector`/`boost::shared_array`/`std::unique_ptr<T[]>` in your case).

Comment: @Koushik Different semantics. It requires `size` to be a compile-time constant, and uses space on the function's "stack".

Answer (score 2):

There is a leak if the ... part after the `arr = new` does not contain a `delete [] arr`, yes.

The solution is to either add a `delete [] arr` at a suitable point, or use `vector<int> arr(size);`, or `unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[size])`.

Which is the "right" choice really depends on what you are overall trying to achieve.

Comment: I think it should be `<int[]>` to use as an array properly. Otherwise, you can cannot index it by `[]` operator.

Comment: @MM.: not only that, but it will use the incorrect form of `delete` (without `[]`) too which is undefined behavior. Most notably, on most platforms it means that only the destructor of the first element will be invoked...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. but you can use below smart pointer to get rid of that:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr (new int[size]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to match up each `new` with a `delete`, and each `new[]` with a `delete[]`.

There are two alternatives. The first is to use a garbage collecting library such as the well-known [Boehm GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

The second, better solution is to use smart pointers. These will call `delete` for you at the appropriate time. There are a couple in the C++ standard library, and Boost has lots more that cover just about every possible use-case.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, all `new`s must have matching `delete`s somewhere. Smart pointers conveniently handle this for you.

Another, non-C++ solution that might apply here would be to not use `new`, but `alloca` from the standard C library. This is more lightweight and you don't have to deallocate, but of course you can blow up the stack if `size` gets too big.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

use a smart pointer

```
template<class C> struct smartpointer
{

    C* data;
    smartpointer():data(NULL){}
    ~smartpointer(){if(data){delete data;data=NULL;}

};
```

this automatically destroy its content when the block expires

Comment: Your smart pointer is not smart enough. Why inventing from scratch where there're `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`?