# Is Qt incompatible with RAII design patterns?

Tags: c++, qt, destructor, smart-pointers, raii

An important rule of thumb for good coding practices is

> every `new` must be matched by a `delete`

discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629773/22764748) previous question. Usually, we encapsulate this rule in an RAII class like `std::unique_ptr`. However, Qt appears to break this pattern. For example, to create a `QTimer`, a user may do something like this:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, QOverload<>::of(&AnalogClock::update));
timer->start(1000);
```

The above example is found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html#details). The `QTimer` constructor is passed the `this` pointer, which becomes the parent of `timer`. It seems that Qt then sets up `*this` to destruct `QTimer` when the destructor for `*this` is called. In effect, there is no need to call `delete timer`.

1. Can I call `delete timer;` anyway, such as in the destructor of a `unique_ptr`? Will that call the destructor twice?
2. What if `timer` was allocated on the stack? Does `*this`  know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I call delete timer anyway

If you explicitly call `delete timer`, the QTimer's destructor (well, to be exact, the destructor of the QTimer's QObject base-class) will remove the QTimer from its parent-object's children-list, so that later on when the parent-object's own destructor is called, the QTimer will not be deleted a second time.  So that's okay.

> such as in the destructor of a unique_ptr

With `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr`), OTOH, you will run into a problem -- while the QObject classes are smart enough to update their parent-QObject when they are destroyed, they do *not* know how to update a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` that is pointing to them.  So if you assign a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to point to your QTimer object, and also give the QTimer-object a non-NULL parent (as in your example), then you likely *will* have a double-delete problem:  once when the Qt mechanism deletes the QTimer, and a second time when the `unique_ptr` tries to delete the (now-dangling) pointer that it contains.   (Note that there is a [QPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpointer.html) class that behaves as a weak-pointer to a QObject, which can be useful).

Because of that, it's better not to try to mix Qt's object-tree system and C++ smart-pointers.  That is, if you're going to give your QTimer a non-NULL parent, then you should rely on that parent to handle the QTimer's deletion, and not also try to manage it with a `unique_ptr`.

> What if timer was allocated on the stack? Does *this know that?

No, `this`'s destructor won't know the object is on the stack, and so it will try to delete it, leading to undefined behavior.  So if you're going to allocate the QTimer on the stack, you should not specify a non-NULL parent-pointer for it.

Comment: "So if you're going to allocate the ```QTimer``` on the stack, you should not specify a non-NULL parent-pointer for it." For ```QTimer``` this is fine, but for other classes, doesn't the parent-child relationship handle other things besides ownership, such as window resizing? Wouldn't I lose that if I don't assign a parent?

Comment: @Bobby If you add a widget to a layout, Qt automatically reparents it to the widget on which the layout is set, even if the widget had no parent.

Comment: @Bobby It's fine to have a QObject with parent in stack, as long as the child goes out of scope before parent (and removes itself from parent). Mostly relevant in `main()` and for member variable QObjects (not pointers).

Comment: @Bobby you're right, but generally in the cases where the parent-child relationship matters, you wouldn't want to be placing the child onto the stack anyway, since that would limit the child's lifetime to the execution of the current function, and typically you want the parent-child relationship to survive across multiple iterations of Qt's event loop.

Comment: What if QTimer is allocated on heap with 'this' as parent and exception is thrown by constructor after allocation.  In this case, parent class destructor would not be called .Would this result in memory leak or does Qt handles this somehow?  
Parent_Class_Construcotr(){ 
     QTimer* ptr =  new QTimer(this);
     throw 99; //exception
 }

Comment: @Infinity Qt avoids that problem by promising not to throw any exceptions :). https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/exceptionsafety.html#:~:text=Qt%20itself%20will%20not%20throw,Instead%2C%20error%20codes%20are%20used.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I've some other class instead of QTimer in my last comment, for example say some class derived from QDialog, in that case should I avoid passing parent and use a unique pointer ?

Comment: I'd say avoid throwing exceptions from the constructors of your derived-from-Qt subclasses; that's probably easier than trying to mix Qt's object model with unique-pointer.  But of course it's up to you.